# Open source office suite other than OpenOffice.org?

Tags: microsoft-office, open-source

I do not like MO and OOo (Microsoft Office, OpenOffice.org).

Is there any other VERY good free office for Windows/Mac/Linux?

Comment: Do you want free or open source? You have an open source tag, but your questions says free.

Comment: What don't you like about them?

Comment: See also "Free office suites: the most compatible with Microsoft Office?" at http://superuser.com/questions/19479/free-office-suites-the-most-compatible-with-microsoft-office

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) is a web-based office suite.  It does a number of things very well while in other ways lagging behind application-based office suites.

Comment: Note that this is not open sourced, but is free.

Comment: Also, the Documents are stored online...I leave it to you if this is a downside or not.

Comment: But you can download them in many different formats

Comment: That's when the conversion works - I've stopped using Google Docs when it started mangling the output as Word documents.  Maybe fixed by now, but I've moved on.

Answer (score 7):

[GNOME Office](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeOffice) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Office)) is also available for Linux.  It includes:

- [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) ([win port](http://www.abisource.com/download/)) (word processor),
- [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) ([win port](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/downloads.shtml)) (spreadsheet),
- [Evolution](http://www.gnome.org/projects/evolution/) ([win port](http://www.dipconsultants.com/evolution/)) (contact manager, etc),
- [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) ([win port](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=192)) (accounting)

...as well as other utilities.  Some of these are available for Windows as well.

Comment: was going to suggest Abiword as well

Answer (score 4):

There's the K-Office suite for Linux, KDE

Or you can use an online office - google has it

Comment: good point, hadn't been thinking cloud office options, but now you mention it, there's also Zoho (http://www.zoho.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) is a multi platform application, reads many standard document types (OpenOffice, MS Word, WordPerfect, RTF, HTML...) and has a good layout capabilities. As the program is very small, it requires very little resources and can be used on even older machines. It is extendable via plugins.

[image]

There's also [SSuite Office - The Fifth Element](http://ssuite5element.webs.com/thefifthelement.htm) with an innovative interface.

Another office suite light on resources is [SoftMaker Office 2006 for Windows](http://www.softmakeroffice.com/).

There's also the [ZOHO](https://www.zoho.com/) ***online*** office suite.

Answer (score 0):

Try NeoOffice as an alternative to OpenOffice. It's based on OpenOffice though, so I'm not sure if this fixes any issues you have with OOo. But since you don't specify what they *are*, it's hard to tell.