# Choosing office suite

Tags: microsoft-office, openoffice, office-suite, lotus-symphony

Microsoft Office is not free.
OpenOffice is free but really slow.
IBM Lotus Symphony is free but really slow.

What's the solution?
EDIT: Is there any fast and free office suite?

Comment: What's the solution to what? You haven't told us what your requirements are.

Comment: "free" and "fast" is not a very useful list of requirements. What OS(es) do you need to have supported? Do you care if it's stable? What features do you need?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the Office Suite? Have you thought of Google Docs? Or do you need more features... I wouldn't know because you have not provided us an idea of what you want to do with this office suite....

Comment: I'm using **WPS Office Personal Edition** which is free and small (33M), It looks like Microsoft Office 2003, and can **read** files in Microsoft Office 2007 format. Unfortunately, the GUI language is Chinese. There's equivalant Kingsoft Office whose GUI language is English, but it's not free. For more information, check out their websites http://www.kingsoftresearch.com/kso.php , http://www.wps.cn

Comment: Possible duplicat - http://superuser.com/questions/19479/free-office-suites-the-most-compatible-with-microsoft-office

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making some sweeping generalisations about complex pieces of software, so here are some sweeping generalisations of my own...

Microsoft Office is heavily optimised for Windows and was developed with the extensive resources available to Microsoft. The free suites are less optimised for a particular platform and are arguably less mature products, but the features are good and the price is great.

If you want the best of both worlds in this particular case, you'll need to pay for Microsoft Office or pay for faster hardware to run the free suites.

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice is now in the hands of the Apache Foundation, before that Oracle pretty much ended development.

LibreOffice is its replacement, basically OpenOffice has been forked into LibreOffice:

http://www.libreoffice.org/

Depending on your needs, you may not need an office suite, both Microsoft and Google have web based office applications:

Office Web Apps:
http://skydrive.live.com/

Google Docs:
http://docs.google.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend LibreOffice. It has all the features of OpenOffice, but shows significant improvements and was also reported to be quicker.

Otherwise, on linux you can try so called Gnome Office, which is (I think) combination of Abiword, Gnumeric etc. For me it was not the right choice, so I use LibreOffice.

KDE also has something, but never used ...

Comment: gnomeoffice runs on windows = abiword is nice as a standalone wordprocessor, but dosen't handle office 2007 files well IMO, and there's no powerpoint equivilent . KDE has Koffice, and its fork Calligra, neither of which has a working windows port yet.